# Class element highlight which depends on variable

Tags: jquery, html, css, twig

What's the situation? I've got following code in html.twig file :

```
<div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

        {% if site == 'users'%}
              ...
            <li class="active"><a href="...">User list</a></li>
            <li><a href="...">Register</a></li>

        {% elseif site == 'registration' %}
            <li><a href="welcome">Home</a></li>
              ...
            <li class="active"><a href="...">Register</a></li>

        {% else if site == '...' %}
          .
          .
          .
        {% endif %}
```

It's extremely 'dirty-looking', forces to repeat code multiple times and reusability does not exist at all in that case.

What's the goal? The goal is to shorten this code by placing all the `<a href="...">` links only once. In some way however, class="active" parameter must be included in one of the `<a>` tags - depending on variable data.

**My solution** (sub-optimal):

Here's what I've done using Twig 'set' operand. But still code is pretty long and It uses as many {% if %} clauses as possible variable values are.

```
        {% set welcome_but = ''  %}
                        ...
        {% set reg_but = ''  %}

        {% if site == 'users'%}
            {% set user_but = 'active'  %}
                          ...
        {% elseif site == 'registration' %}
            {% set reg_but = 'active'  %}

        {% endif %}

            <li class="{{ welcome_but }}"><a href="...">Home</a></li>
            <li class="{{ reg_but }}"><a href="...">Register</a></li>
```

**What's the question?**

How to reach optimal solution - i.e to use one 'if' or 'bind' statement instead of current, linear progression of 'if' statements occurrences with number of possible values. Maybe JS function or jQuery solution should be used?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @BarbaraLaird How to reach optimal solution - i.e to use one if or 'bind' statement instead of current, linear progression of 'if' statements occurrences with number of possible values.

Comment: To clarify, you have a list of links and wish to show/hide each one based on the 'site' variable?  And your code above has a lot of duplication which you want to reduce?

Comment: @Quantumplate Yes, for example if 'site' variable equals to 'index', the following link should contain 'active' class :  <a href="index.html" class="active"> and if not (for example equals to 'users'), the link mentioned above shouldn't contain any class : <a href="index.html">. And so for all links.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a concise way of printing a known array of links with Twig

```
{# Set array with links #}
{% set linkArray = [{'name': 'Home', 'href': '#home', 'site': 'user'},
    {'name': 'Register', 'href': '#register', 'site': 'registration'}] %}

<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
{# Iterate over items #}
{% for i, item in linkArray %}
   <li{% if site == item.site%} class="active"{% endif %}>
      <a href="{{ item.href }}">{{ item.name }}</a>
   </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Take a look at https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle for advanced menus handling capabilities.

More specifically see how they rock menus:
https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenu/blob/master/src/Knp/Menu/Resources/views/knp_menu.html.twig